# Convert PDF to CMYK

Tags: gratis, pdf, image-conversion, color

What free (and preferrably but not neccessarily open source) tools can convert PDF from mixed use of colorspaces to pure CMYK in the output PDF. It has to convert both vector and raster graphics.

Bonus points for:

- Open source
- Multi-platform support: Windows, Linux, OS X
- Command line interface (exclusively or in addition to GUI)
- Support for color profiles
- [Trapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_%28printing%29) support
- Full [PDF/X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/X) conformance

Answer (score 1):

Color Management is quite demanding, and requires a good amount of resources to implement (to properly implement). So, this is something which is not just thrown after an user as a goodie.

That said, you might have some success with Ghostscript …if you know what you are doing.

Comment: I tried to tackle a specific case, where the PDF was the result of an SVG exported by Inkscape, in [this question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10937/1304). The (currently only) [answer there](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/10939/1304) suggests Ghostscript as well, but in my experiments I couldn't get it to convert raster images. Do you have any experience there?