# Render SVG to PDF/X-1a

Tags: pdf, svg, image-conversion, color

What tools are there to convert resp. render a SVG file to a conforming [PDF/X-1a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/X) file? The tool should be able to raster filter effects at configurable resolution. It should accept user-configured CMYK colors, particularly if linked to an ICC profile, but it should make a reasonable effort to convert to CMYK where the user specified colors in RGB. FOSS would be best, but a reasonably-priced proprietary solution might be acceptable as well. Big graphics suites in excess of 100$ are not, though.

Answer (score 1):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) can read a file in SVG format and save it as pdf v1.4 or v1.3 and allows a lot of possible manipulations but does not explisetly support producucing PDF/X but it can also output as Postscript, (.ps), then if you really need pdf/X you can run it through [Ghostscripts](http://ghostscript.com/) [ps2pdf](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm) which supports specifying -dPDFX=1 to force PDF/X-3 restrictions and also supports substituting a non-trivial Default Device Colour Space.

- Both Inkscape and GhostScript are Free (Libre and FLOSS)
- Both are Cross platform but you would probably be better off on Linux as they are better supported there.
- I am not sure about CMYK support but I am reasonably confident that it is there.

Comment: I tried using `pdfwrite` of GPL GhostScript 9.14, with `-dPDFX=1`, `-sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK` and `-sColorConversionStrategy=/CMYK`. The result still has a `/DeviceRGB` raster image, though. This might correspond to the documentation for ProcessColorModel which reads: “Note that this does not affect images”

Answer (score 0):

One easier option is to use [ImageMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/) [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) with the [-colourspace](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colorspace) option &/or the [-profile](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#profile) operator, *note that it actually uses both Inkscape and GhostScript, (if installed), for SVG & pdf formatting so you will need both present and on your path*.

- Free (Libre and FLOSS)
- Cross Platform

Comment: This will rasterize *everything*, not just the filter effects. I actually did create a CMYK version of my SVG yesterday, and at one point I did use convert to change the rasterized filter effects to CMYK. But I also separated layers, used pdftk to uncompress the vector data, and sed to change colors in there. A lot of manual work there, and hardly applicable to all SVG images, so I'm still very much interested in a more automatic approach.